# Forecasting error in R when passing around arguments in forecast() and ar()

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

When trying to compose a function from smaller ones using Rob Hyndman's forecast library, like so:

```
> library('forecast')
> arf <- function(data, ...) forecast(ar(data, order.max=1, method="ols"), ...)
```

I get an error when trying to plug in some data:

```
> arf(ts(1:100, start=c(2000,1), frequency=4))
Error in ts(x, frequency = 1, start = 1) : object is not a matrix
```

However, using the body of arf directly works perfectly:

```
> forecast(ar(ts(1:100, start=c(2000,1), frequency=4), order.max=1,method="ols"))
        Point Forecast Lo 80 Hi 80 Lo 95 Hi 95
2025 Q1            101   101   101   101   101
2025 Q2            102   102   102   102   102
2025 Q3            103   103   103   103   103
2025 Q4            104   104   104   104   104
2026 Q1            105   105   105   105   105
2026 Q2            106   106   106   106   106
2026 Q3            107   107   107   107   107
2026 Q4            108   108   108   108   108
2027 Q1            109   109   109   109   109
2027 Q2            110   110   110   110   110
```

Why does arf not work as it should?

Comment: This is very weired indeed. It looks like a bug in `forecast.ar` method as I was able to run this with `forecast.Arima` method while replacing `ar` with `auto.arima`. Let's wait for @RobHyndman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem (not really a bug) in `forecast.ar()`. All `forecast.xxx()` functions try to store the data used to estimate the time series model as it is required for plots and accuracy calculations. However, `ar()` does not return the data, so `forecast.ar()` attempts to find the data in the calling environment, or in the parent environment. When you call `forecast(ar(...))` directly, the function manages to find the data, but `arf()` places the call to `ar()` one level deeper making it that much harder for `forecast` to figure out what data was being used.

I can modify the function to make it look harder for the data (i.e., look in the grandparent environment also), but the construction will still fail because `predict.ar()` (part of the `stats` package) will then cause a similar error.  It would be *much* better if `ar()` returned the data, but `ar()` is part of the `stats` package and I have no control over it.

There are several possible solutions.

1. You could replace `ar` with `Arima`:

   ```
   arf <- function(dat, ...) forecast(Arima(dat, order=c(1,0,0)), ...)
   ```

   That should return the same model if the data are stationary (although the parameter estimates will be slightly different). It won't return the same answer for the example in your question because the time series is non-stationary.
2. You could use `auto.arima()` instead if you were willing to use more general ARIMA models than AR(1).

   ```
   arf <- function(dat, ...) forecast(auto.arima(dat, ...)
   ```
3. (Based on a suggestion from @agstudy). A workaround is to ensure the data is stored within the `ar` object:

   ```
   arf <- function(dat, ...) 
   {
     object <- ar(dat, order.max=1, method="ols")
     object$x <- dat
     forecast(object,...)
   }
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using non-stationary data @RobHyndman. Your third suggestion (the workaround) worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is a bug in the S3 method predict for `ar` class. `predict.ar` try to evaluate the newdata parameter using `ar` object. Showing the first lines of `getS3method('predict','ar')`

```
function (object, newdata, n.ahead = 1L, se.fit = TRUE, ...) 
{
    if (n.ahead < 1L) 
        stop("'n.ahead' must be at least 1")
    if (missing(newdata)) {
        newdata <- eval.parent(parse(text = object$series))
        if (!is.null(nas <- object$call$na.action)) 
            newdata <- eval.parent(call(nas, newdata))
    }

  .....
}
```

the relevant/bugged line is:

```
 newdata <- eval.parent(parse(text = object$series))
```

But object$series don't have the right expression/character. since it is hidden by the new level of wrapper function arf. Here a workaround, is to set the right expression for this term:

```
arf <- function(dat, ...) 
  {
    object <- ar(dat, order.max=1, method="ols")
    object$series <- as.character(as.expression(as.list(match.call())$dat))
    forecast(object,...)
}
arf( ts(1:100, start=c(2000,1), frequency=4)
```

Note that ; this solution works also with:

```
aa <- ts(1:100, start=c(2000,1), frequency=4)
arf(aa)
```

Comment: 11 hours after the question, we answered within 4 minutes of each other, and I didn't see this until I finished my answer.

Comment: @RobHyndman mee too! I didn't see your answer also! I am saying that you can be in holidays so maybe I can help :) I think I will delete my answer since it is a workaround and not a real solution...

Comment: What about we combine them, as your solution is useful if the OP really wants to use `ar()` with `method="ols"`.

Comment: @RobHyndman Of course professor, you are free to use my answer as you like. It is Better Then I use your answer to modify mine (better English and better knowledge of "your" subject")