# Predict arima() with newxreg fails due to different number of columns despite have the same number of columns

Tags: r

I'm able to predict from an arima() object using newxreg, but after appending the predictions to the original data.frame, I cannot generate that same prediction anymore, despite specifying the exact same columns in newxreg.

Below is a reproducible example with minimal packages. Thank you in advance for any guidance on this issue.

```r
df <- datasets::airquality

yx <- cbind(y=df[, "Temp"], df[, c("Ozone", "Wind")])

mod <- arima(ts(yx$y[1:100]), order = c(3,0,0), xreg = yx[1:100,-c(1)], include.mean = FALSE)
mod
#> 
#> Call:
#> arima(x = ts(yx$y[1:100]), order = c(3, 0, 0), xreg = yx[1:100, -c(1)], include.mean = FALSE)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>          ar1      ar2     ar3   Ozone     Wind
#>       0.5022  -0.0715  0.5684  0.0959  -0.0805
#> s.e.  0.1361   0.1514  0.1403  0.0224   0.1717
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 19.62:  log likelihood = -208.24,  aic = 428.47

# Works 
p <- c(yx$y[1:100] , predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE))
predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE)
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 101 
#> End = 153 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>      101      102      103      104      105      106      107      108 
#> 91.74904       NA       NA 85.13929 83.60528 87.29768       NA 83.12668 
#>      109      110      111      112      113      114      115      116 
#> 86.99629 83.45615 83.94124 85.23595 82.61195 81.55809       NA 85.38016 
#>      117      118      119      120      121      122      123      124 
#> 97.68038 88.20162       NA 88.35232 92.97518 89.39320 89.48907 90.49538 
#>      125      126      127      128      129      130      131      132 
#> 88.91460 88.62048 90.20126 85.75718 83.66658 82.88660 83.22256 82.98247 
#>      133      134      135      136      137      138      139      140 
#> 83.36676 84.86543 82.61195 84.02414 81.83196 82.16714 85.70158 82.46125 
#>      141      142      143      144      145      146      147      148 
#> 82.26380 83.31843 82.73669 82.07853 83.31116 84.46895 81.68854 81.85221 
#>      149      150      151      152      153 
#> 84.16756       NA 82.03747 82.92844 82.83827

# Does not work
yx$p <- c(yx$y[1:100] , predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE))
head(yx)
#>    y Ozone Wind  p
#> 1 67    41  7.4 67
#> 2 72    36  8.0 72
#> 3 74    12 12.6 74
#> 4 62    18 11.5 62
#> 5 56    NA 14.3 56
#> 6 66    28 14.9 66
predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE)
#> Error in predict.Arima(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", : 'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns

# Does not work (!)
temp <- yx[,-4]
head(temp)
#>    y Ozone Wind
#> 1 67    41  7.4
#> 2 72    36  8.0
#> 3 74    12 12.6
#> 4 62    18 11.5
#> 5 56    NA 14.3
#> 6 66    28 14.9
predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(temp[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE)
#> Error in predict.Arima(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(temp[101:153, c("Ozone", : 'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  French_Canada.1252
#>  ctype    French_Canada.1252
#>  tz       America/New_York
#>  date     2022-06-15
#>  pandoc   2.11.4 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  digest        0.6.28  2021-09-23 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  knitr         1.38    2022-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  rmarkdown     2.13    2022-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  stringi       1.7.4   2021-08-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  xfun          0.30    2022-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#> 
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from the eval.parent(xr) part of the predict.Arima() function. It looks for the current state of the xreg matrix, which now contains the column "p", instead of using the original state of the xreg matrix.

The solutions seems to be to keep the xreg matrix intact, and store anything else elsewhere. Personnally I'm using this in a loop setting, so the yx matrix keeps changing all the time, forcing me to create any prediction *within* the loop. Once outside, the xreg matrix will not match.

Hopefully this is useful!

Related to: [Forecasting error in R when passing around arguments in forecast() and ar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832817/forecasting-error-in-r-when-passing-around-arguments-in-forecast-and-ar)

```r
getAnywhere("predict.Arima")
#> A single object matching 'predict.Arima' was found
#> It was found in the following places
#>   registered S3 method for predict from namespace stats
#>   namespace:stats
#> with value
#> 
#> function (object, n.ahead = 1L, newxreg = NULL, se.fit = TRUE, 
#>     ...) 
#> {
#>     myNCOL <- function(x) if (is.null(x)) 
#>         0
#>     else NCOL(x)
#>     rsd <- object$residuals
#>     xr <- object$call$xreg
#>     xreg <- if (!is.null(xr)) 
#>         eval.parent(xr)
#>     else NULL
#>     ncxreg <- myNCOL(xreg)
#>     if (myNCOL(newxreg) != ncxreg) 
#>         stop("'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns")
#>     xtsp <- tsp(rsd)
#>     n <- length(rsd)
#>     arma <- object$arma
#>     coefs <- object$coef
#>     narma <- sum(arma[1L:4L])
#>     if (length(coefs) > narma) {
#>         if (names(coefs)[narma + 1L] == "intercept") {
#>             newxreg <- cbind(intercept = rep(1, n.ahead), newxreg)
#>             ncxreg <- ncxreg + 1L
#>         }
#>         xm <- if (narma == 0) 
#>             drop(as.matrix(newxreg) %*% coefs)
#>         else drop(as.matrix(newxreg) %*% coefs[-(1L:narma)])
#>     }
#>     else xm <- 0
#>     if (arma[2L] > 0L) {
#>         ma <- coefs[arma[1L] + 1L:arma[2L]]
#>         if (any(Mod(polyroot(c(1, ma))) < 1)) 
#>             warning("MA part of model is not invertible")
#>     }
#>     if (arma[4L] > 0L) {
#>         ma <- coefs[sum(arma[1L:3L]) + 1L:arma[4L]]
#>         if (any(Mod(polyroot(c(1, ma))) < 1)) 
#>             warning("seasonal MA part of model is not invertible")
#>     }
#>     z <- KalmanForecast(n.ahead, object$model)
#>     pred <- ts(z[[1L]] + xm, start = xtsp[2L] + deltat(rsd), 
#>         frequency = xtsp[3L])
#>     if (se.fit) {
#>         se <- ts(sqrt(z[[2L]] * object$sigma2), start = xtsp[2L] + 
#>             deltat(rsd), frequency = xtsp[3L])
#>         list(pred = pred, se = se)
#>     }
#>     else pred
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000009d767e0>
#> <environment: namespace:stats>
      
df <- datasets::airquality

yx <- cbind(y=df[, "Temp"], df[, c("Ozone", "Wind")])

mod <- arima(ts(yx$y[1:100]), order = c(3,0,0), xreg = yx[1:100,-c(1)], include.mean = FALSE)
mod
#> 
#> Call:
#> arima(x = ts(yx$y[1:100]), order = c(3, 0, 0), xreg = yx[1:100, -c(1)], include.mean = FALSE)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>          ar1      ar2     ar3   Ozone     Wind
#>       0.5022  -0.0715  0.5684  0.0959  -0.0805
#> s.e.  0.1361   0.1514  0.1403  0.0224   0.1717
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 19.62:  log likelihood = -208.24,  aic = 428.47

# Works 
p <- c(yx$y[1:100] , predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE))
predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE)
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 101 
#> End = 153 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>      101      102      103      104      105      106      107      108 
#> 91.74904       NA       NA 85.13929 83.60528 87.29768       NA 83.12668 
#>      109      110      111      112      113      114      115      116 
#> 86.99629 83.45615 83.94124 85.23595 82.61195 81.55809       NA 85.38016 
#>      117      118      119      120      121      122      123      124 
#> 97.68038 88.20162       NA 88.35232 92.97518 89.39320 89.48907 90.49538 
#>      125      126      127      128      129      130      131      132 
#> 88.91460 88.62048 90.20126 85.75718 83.66658 82.88660 83.22256 82.98247 
#>      133      134      135      136      137      138      139      140 
#> 83.36676 84.86543 82.61195 84.02414 81.83196 82.16714 85.70158 82.46125 
#>      141      142      143      144      145      146      147      148 
#> 82.26380 83.31843 82.73669 82.07853 83.31116 84.46895 81.68854 81.85221 
#>      149      150      151      152      153 
#> 84.16756       NA 82.03747 82.92844 82.83827

# Does not work
yx$p <- c(yx$y[1:100] , predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE))
head(yx)
#>    y Ozone Wind  p
#> 1 67    41  7.4 67
#> 2 72    36  8.0 72
#> 3 74    12 12.6 74
#> 4 62    18 11.5 62
#> 5 56    NA 14.3 56
#> 6 66    28 14.9 66
predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE)
#> Error in predict.Arima(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", : 'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns

# Does not work (!)
temp <- yx[,-4]
head(temp)
#>    y Ozone Wind
#> 1 67    41  7.4
#> 2 72    36  8.0
#> 3 74    12 12.6
#> 4 62    18 11.5
#> 5 56    NA 14.3
#> 6 66    28 14.9
predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(temp[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE)
#> Error in predict.Arima(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(temp[101:153, c("Ozone", : 'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns

# eval.parent() finds the current state of yx, not its original state
xr <- mod$call$xreg
eval.parent(xr)
#>     Ozone Wind  p
#> 1      41  7.4 67
#> 2      36  8.0 72
#> 3      12 12.6 74
#> 4      18 11.5 62
#> 5      NA 14.3 56
#> 6      28 14.9 66
#> 7      23  8.6 65
#> 8      19 13.8 59
#> 9       8 20.1 61
#> 10     NA  8.6 69
#> 11      7  6.9 74
#> 12     16  9.7 69
#> 13     11  9.2 66
#> 14     14 10.9 68
#> 15     18 13.2 58
#> 16     14 11.5 64
#> 17     34 12.0 66
#> 18      6 18.4 57
#> 19     30 11.5 68
#> 20     11  9.7 62
#> 21      1  9.7 59
#> 22     11 16.6 73
#> 23      4  9.7 61
#> 24     32 12.0 61
#> 25     NA 16.6 57
#> 26     NA 14.9 58
#> 27     NA  8.0 57
#> 28     23 12.0 67
#> 29     45 14.9 81
#> 30    115  5.7 79
#> 31     37  7.4 76
#> 32     NA  8.6 78
#> 33     NA  9.7 74
#> 34     NA 16.1 67
#> 35     NA  9.2 84
#> 36     NA  8.6 85
#> 37     NA 14.3 79
#> 38     29  9.7 82
#> 39     NA  6.9 87
#> 40     71 13.8 90
#> 41     39 11.5 87
#> 42     NA 10.9 93
#> 43     NA  9.2 92
#> 44     23  8.0 82
#> 45     NA 13.8 80
#> 46     NA 11.5 79
#> 47     21 14.9 77
#> 48     37 20.7 72
#> 49     20  9.2 65
#> 50     12 11.5 73
#> 51     13 10.3 76
#> 52     NA  6.3 77
#> 53     NA  1.7 76
#> 54     NA  4.6 76
#> 55     NA  6.3 76
#> 56     NA  8.0 75
#> 57     NA  8.0 78
#> 58     NA 10.3 73
#> 59     NA 11.5 80
#> 60     NA 14.9 77
#> 61     NA  8.0 83
#> 62    135  4.1 84
#> 63     49  9.2 85
#> 64     32  9.2 81
#> 65     NA 10.9 84
#> 66     64  4.6 83
#> 67     40 10.9 83
#> 68     77  5.1 88
#> 69     97  6.3 92
#> 70     97  5.7 92
#> 71     85  7.4 89
#> 72     NA  8.6 82
#> 73     10 14.3 73
#> 74     27 14.9 81
#> 75     NA 14.9 91
#> 76      7 14.3 80
#> 77     48  6.9 81
#> 78     35 10.3 82
#> 79     61  6.3 84
#> 80     79  5.1 87
#> 81     63 11.5 85
#> 82     16  6.9 74
#> 83     NA  9.7 81
#> 84     NA 11.5 82
#> 85     80  8.6 86
#> 86    108  8.0 85
#> 87     20  8.6 82
#> 88     52 12.0 86
#> 89     82  7.4 88
#> 90     50  7.4 86
#> 91     64  7.4 83
#> 92     59  9.2 81
#> 93     39  6.9 81
#> 94      9 13.8 81
#> 95     16  7.4 82
#> 96     78  6.9 86
#> 97     35  7.4 85
#> 98     66  4.6 87
#> 99    122  4.0 89
#> 100    89 10.3 90

# Works
yx2 <- yx
yx <- yx[,-4]
predict(mod, newxreg = as.matrix(yx[101:153, c("Ozone", "Wind")]), se.fit = FALSE)
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 101 
#> End = 153 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>      101      102      103      104      105      106      107      108 
#> 91.74904       NA       NA 85.13929 83.60528 87.29768       NA 83.12668 
#>      109      110      111      112      113      114      115      116 
#> 86.99629 83.45615 83.94124 85.23595 82.61195 81.55809       NA 85.38016 
#>      117      118      119      120      121      122      123      124 
#> 97.68038 88.20162       NA 88.35232 92.97518 89.39320 89.48907 90.49538 
#>      125      126      127      128      129      130      131      132 
#> 88.91460 88.62048 90.20126 85.75718 83.66658 82.88660 83.22256 82.98247 
#>      133      134      135      136      137      138      139      140 
#> 83.36676 84.86543 82.61195 84.02414 81.83196 82.16714 85.70158 82.46125 
#>      141      142      143      144      145      146      147      148 
#> 82.26380 83.31843 82.73669 82.07853 83.31116 84.46895 81.68854 81.85221 
#>      149      150      151      152      153 
#> 84.16756       NA 82.03747 82.92844 82.83827
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  French_Canada.1252
#>  ctype    French_Canada.1252
#>  tz       America/New_York
#>  date     2022-06-15
#>  pandoc   2.11.4 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  digest        0.6.28  2021-09-23 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  knitr         1.38    2022-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  rmarkdown     2.13    2022-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  stringi       1.7.4   2021-08-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  xfun          0.30    2022-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```